# how to create a file with .aidl extension?

Tags: android, aidl

I have following questions

1. Do i need to create a simple file with .aidl extension ?
2. I read that a corresponding .java file will be created, but in my case when i created a .aidl file;i couldn't find any such .java file
3. is there any particular folder where i need to create this .aidl file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a .aidl file for objects to be passed through IBinder. You should create the .aidl file in the same package as the Java object that it defines.

[Google Developer, Android Interface Definition Language (AIDL)](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer:

1. If you need create a Service, you need create a .aidl file to define the API first.
2. If you have create a .aidl file, the ADT will automatically create the correspoding .java file in the gen/your-package-name folder.
3. No. After you create the file, you should follow the steps:

   a. define the API in .aidl

   b. create your service which extends from android Service class

   c. create a instance which implements XXX.Stub (XXX is your .aidl filename)

   d. bind your service

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
/********************Application 1 Isum.aidl*****************
package com.example.Isum;

interface Isum{

int sum(int a, int b);

}

/***********************Application 1*********Don't do anything in main
/********create service class*********remote service
public class RemoteService extends Service{



    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {


        return mBinder;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
    }
private final Isum.Stub mBinder=new Isum.Stub() {

        @Override
        public int sum(int a, int b) throws RemoteException {


            int c=a+b;
            return c;
        }
    };

**********************Application 2  Main activity*********
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Isum msum;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Button btnSum=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnResult);


        btnSum.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                bindService(new Intent("com.example.serviceprovider.RemoteService"),
                        mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

                        EditText FirstNo=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ETfirstNo);
                        EditText SecondNo=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ETSecondNo);

                        int a=Integer.parseInt(FirstNo.getText().toString());
                        System.out.println("###########"+a);
                        int b=Integer.parseInt(SecondNo.getText().toString());

                        try {

                            int c=msum.sum(a, b);
                            System.out.println("***********************"+c);


                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, c, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



                        } catch (Exception e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
            }
        });


    }

    private ServiceConnection mConnection=new ServiceConnection(){

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName arg0, IBinder arg1) {

            msum=Isum.Stub.asInterface(arg1);

        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
            msum=null;


        }

    };

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
/****************include this in mainfest file


 <service android:name="RemoteService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.serviceprovider.RemoteService"/> 
                 </intent-filter>
           </service>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this, RemoteService.class);
    bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}


public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
    mIsum=Isum.Stub.asInterface((IBinder)service);
    mBound=true;
    }
```